# Jasmine unit tests fail after adding angulartics with the angulartics-piwik

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angulartics

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)e Service should get by id from Service FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET /users/currentuser
    No more request expected in /static/third-party/angularjs/1.4.7/js/angular-mocks.js (line 1245)
```

this is the error message i receive for my services. Before adding angulartics i wouldn't get those messages

Is there any way to make sure these errors dont happen

my testing code :

```
beforeEach(function() {

    module('appHost');
    module('angulartics');

    inject(function($httpBackend, _Service_) {

        Service= _Service_;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    });

});

afterEach(function() {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});

it('should get template by id from Service', function() {

    var expected = {
            "name": "my name",
            "description": "bla bla bla bla",

        };

    var id = "12345";
    httpBackend.expectGET("/data/"+id).respond(expected);
        });
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced something similar.  My fix was simply to add this line

```
httpBackend.whenGET(/users/currentuser/).respond(200, '');
```

in the before each block.  Then I got another error as angular was trying to get it's own templates.  I fixed that by making changes to the karma pre-processor config to strip the prefix in question.  Let me know if you need any more help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `httpBackend.flush()`

```
it('should get template by id from Service', function() {

    var expected = {
            "name": "my name",
            "description": "bla bla bla bla",

        };

    var id = "12345";
    httpBackend.expectGET("/data/"+id).respond(expected);
    httpBackend.flush()
});
```

Comment: For me the httpBackend.flush() was triggering the `Unexpected request: GET` that I circumvented with the change to the karma conf.